# Groovy JsonSlurper - How to check for null value vs missing field?

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I am parsing a JSON string with Groovy's JsonSlurper. I want to find out how to (1) check if a field is missing from the string OR (2) if its value is set to null. This is my code:

```
def JsonSlurper jSlurp = new JsonSlurper()
def obj = jSlurp.parseText(myJsonString)
assert obj.myField == null
```

Unfortunately, this does not tell me if the field is missing or if its present with a value of null. How do I figure that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def obj = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('{"a":null, "b":1}')
assert obj.containsKey('a')==true
assert obj.a==null

assert obj.containsKey('c')==false
assert obj.c==null
```

Comment: In the last line of code, did you mean obj.c == null instead of obj.a ?